# Number of integers $n$ between 1 and 1000 such that the HCF of $n$ and $36$ is 1

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, inclusion-exclusion

> How many integers $n$ are there such that $1< n < 1000$ and the highest common factor of $n$ and $36$ is $1$?

I have tried counting the  prime numbers up to $1000$ using the prime-counting function. But there are of course other numbers like $133$, $77$ which are not prime and yet they satisfy the conditions.

Is there any efficient algorithm to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

In order for the greatest common factor of an integer $n$ and $36$ to be $1$, $n$ and $36$ must share no prime divisors.  The prime divisors of $36$ are $2$ and $3$.

Thus, the question now becomes:

> How many integers $1 \leq n \leq 1000$ are *not* multiples of $2$ or $3$?

This is fairly easy to compute by looking at the compliment and utilizing the inclusion/exclusion principle --- let $m_k$ be the number of multiples of $k$ between $1$ and $1000$:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{nonmultiples} = 1000 - \left(m_2 + m_3 - m_6\right)
\end{equation}

It can also be seen that the value of $m_k$ is $\left\lfloor\frac{1000}{k}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: Why are we including the multiples of 6.?  Actually I cannot fully understand the solution.

Comment: @AyusDas Since some numbers are multiples of both $2$ and $3$ i.e. multiples of $6$. They are included in both $m_2,m_3$. The formula is a direct consequence of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: I have understood. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since $36 = 2*2*3*3$, $\gcd(n,36) = 1$ iff $n$ is not divisible by $2$ or $3$. Hence

First we find the number of integers $< 1000$ which are divisible by $2$ or $3$. The we will subtract this number from $999$ to get our required answer.

No. of integers $< 1000$ which are divisible by $2 = [999/2] = 499$

No. of integers $< 1000$ which are divisible by $3 = [999/3] = 333$

But some numbers which are divisible by both $2$ and $3$ i.e. multiples of $6$. So to avoid double counting we need to subtract these multiples of $6$

No. of integers $< 1000$ which are divisible by $6 = [999/6] = 166$

Hence No. of integrs $< 1000$ which have $HCF > 1$ with $36 = 499 + 333 - 166 = 666$

Hence No. of integrs $< 1000$ which have $HCF = 1$ with $36 = 999 - 666 = 333$

Comment: Ok. I understood this

Comment: Your answer says "No. of integers $< 1000$ which are divisible by $2 = [999/2]+1 = 499$". The "$+1$" part should be removed as it's incorrect. Also, I believe that using square brackets is the not the standard way to indicate the largest integer operation. Instead, I suggest using the floor function, e.g., $\lfloor 999/2 \rfloor$.